# Filtering text encoded with utf-8 to only contain latin alphabet characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to filter textdata to only contain latin characters, for further text analyzing. The original textsource most likely contained **Korean Alphabet.** This shows up like this in the text file:

```
\xe7\xac\xac8\xe4\xbd\x8d ONE PIECE FILM GOLD Blu-ray GOLDEN LIMITED EDITION
```

What would be the fastest/easiest/most complete way to get remove these? I tried making a script that would remove all \xXX combinations, but it turns out that there are to many exceptions for this to be reliable.

Is there a way to remove all none latin characters from utf-8 encoded text?

Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION:

```
import string

textin = b'\xe7\xac\xac8\xe4\xbd\x8d ONE PIECE FILM GOLD Blu-ray GOLDEN LIMITED EDITION'.decode('UTF-8')
outtext = ''

for char in textin:
    if char in string.printable:
        outtext += char

print(outtext)
```

my data was decoded to bits for some reason, don't ask me why. :D

Comment: "Non-Latin" or "non-ASCII"?

Comment: `s.decode('utf-8').encode('latin1', 'ignore').decode('latin1')`.

Comment: It's Chinese, not Korean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this:

```
import string

intext = b'<your funny characters>'
outtext = ''

for char in intext.decode('utf-8'):
    if char in string.ascii_letters:
        outtext += char
```

I'm not sure this is what you want however. For the given intext, outtext is empty. If you append string.digits to string.ascii_letters, outtext is '11'.

(edited to fix a mistake in the code, pointed out by OP)

Comment: Thank bart, a little question though, text in text.decode() should be intext right? Otherwise I don't know what its referring to. I'm going to try and elaborate my question. I have a lot of textdata, that was originally encoded with utf-8. When loading my data from the file, even when specifiying the encoding, it still ends up with the above mentioned, weird text. I have 0 experience with text encoding, but there has to be a way to reverse that, and then filter out non-latin (non ascii?) characters?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out what the problem was. I edited the toppost

Comment: Yes, you're right about the mistake in my code. I fixed it, sorry. Was due to a last-minute change. :-/

Happy to read you found a solution based on my suggestion. :-)

Answer (score -1):

While reading the csv file, try to do the encoding as:

```
df=pd.read_csv('D:/sample.csv',encoding="utf-8-sig")
```