# Python - Remove extended ascii

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, utf-8

Okay, so I am new to the whole python world so bear with me.

Background: We are trying to offload logs into mongo to be able to query and search for them quicker. The device already prints them in a decent format EXCEPT in between each }{ to begin and end the data object something like this:

```
¾ïúÀï{"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,"payloadType":"xxx","payload":{"protocol":"xxx","zoneID":xxx,"zoneName":"xxx","eventType":"xxx"}}’ÂCº¾ïúÀï{"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,"payloadType":"xxx","payload":{"protocol":"xxx","zoneID":xxx,"zoneName":"xxx","eventType":"xx}}
```

Using the following I've been able to convert it to bytes then back to a string which outputs as:

```
f = open('logfile', 'r')
file_data = f.read()
f.close()

data = file_data.encode('utf-8')

print(str(data))

>>>b'\xc2\xbe\xc3\xaf\xc3\xba\xc3\x80\x01\xc3\xaf{"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,"payloadType":"xxx","payload":{"protocol":"xxx","zoneID":xxx,"zoneName":"xxx","eventType":"xxx"}}
```

In my mind this is easier to deal with than the ugly characters seen above but I don't know.

This is just a sample..there are thousands upon thousands of lines returned in this log. In my mind, ideally the best way to go about this would be to remove all characters at the beginning of the string before { and all characters in between }}{

Comment: use c# ;) just kidding, I can't help ya!

Answer (score 3):

Encode the string to bytes and then decode back to ASCII:

```
data.encode().decode('ascii',errors='ignore')
# {"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,...}}
```

You can also use regular expressions to remove all characters outside of the outermost curly braces:

```
re.sub(r'^[^{]*(?={)|(?<=})[^}{]*(?={)|(?<=})[^}]*$', '', data)
```

The latter mechanism incidentally also removes the ASCII 'C' character that you do not want.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

str='¾ïúÀï{"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,"payloadType":"xxx","payload":{"protocol":"xxx","zoneID":xxx,"zoneName":"xxx","eventType":"xxx"}}’ÂCº¾ïúÀï{"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,"payloadType":"xxx","payload":{"protocol":"xxx","zoneID":xxx,"zoneName":"xxx","eventType":"xx}}'

str=re.sub('[^\x00-\x7F]','',str)
print(str)
```

Should produce output as...

```
'{"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,"payloadType":"xxx","payload":{"protocol":"xxx","zoneID":xxx,"zoneName":"xxx","eventType":"xxx"}}C{"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,"payloadType":"xxx","payload":{"protocol":"xxx","zoneID":xxx,"zoneName":"xxx","eventType":"xx}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

what about something like:

```
import string

cleaned_string = ''
for char in ugly_string:
    if char in string.printable:
        cleaned_string += char
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059104/filtering-text-encoded-with-utf-8-to-only-contain-latin-alphabet-characters/46059540#46059540) also deals with a similar problem.

Comment: note: this leaves behind an extraneous `C`, notice it here  ---> `'{"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,"payloadType":"xxx","payload":{"protocol":"xxx","zoneID":xxx,"zoneName":"xxx","eventType":"xxx"}}C{"id":"xxx","timestamp":xxx,"payloadType":"xxx","payload":{"protocol":"xxx","zoneID":xxx,"zoneName":"xxx","eventType":"xx}}'`

Comment: @aws_apprentice No matter how you proceed, there is no way to tell that C from any other legal ASCII character.

Comment: indeed. if the C is recurrent and predictable in that position however, it could be used to split the string into parts readable by `json.loads`. :-)

Comment: A clear way to express your solution: `''.join(char for char in data if char in string.printable)`

Comment: yes, that's essentially the same. not convinced if it's "a clear way" however, but I like it. thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the garbage bytes do not contain opening curly braces, you can do something like this:

```
def decode_all(data):
    decoder = JSONDecoder()
    end_index = 0

    while data:
        try:
            data = data[data.index('{', end_index):]
        except ValueError:
            break

        obj, end_index = decoder.raw_decode(data)
        yield obj
```

Otherwise, without knowing what those garbage bytes can contain and whether or not your JSON is pure ASCII, I think the best solution would be to try parsing a JSON-encoded object out of your data over and over and skipping the garbage bytes implicitly:

```
from json import JSONDecoder

data = '''¾ïúÀï{"id":"123","timestamp":123,"payloadType":"123","payload":{"protocol":"123","zoneID":123,"zoneName":"123","eventType":"123"}}’ÂCº¾ïúÀï{"id":"123","timestamp":123,"payloadType":"123","payload":{"protocol":"123","zoneID":123,"zoneName":"123","eventType":"xx"}}'''

def decode_all(data):
    decoder = JSONDecoder()

    while data:
        try:
            obj, end_index = decoder.raw_decode(data)
            data = data[end_index:]

            yield obj
        except ValueError:
            end_index = None

        start = data.find('{')

        if start == -1:
            break
        elif end_index is None and start == 0:
            start = 1

        data = data[start:]

for o in decode_all(data):
    print(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used **exifread**. In short, use **.printable** to get a string of the value.
Here is the code to get the value of some select tags and pack them in a dictionary called context:

```
photo_file = '/absolute/path/photo.jpg'
f = open(latest_f, 'rb')
tags = exifread.process_file(f)
select_tags = ['Image Make', 'Image Model','EXIF DateTimeOriginal', 'EXIF ExposureTime']
context = dict()
for i, tag in enumerate(select_tags):
   context[tag] = tags[select_tags[i]]*.printable*
print(context)
```